# @Inject not working in MethodInterceptor managed by HK2

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, interceptor, hk2

I am currently refactoring a Jersey Web App and want to bundle some cross cutting concerns in their own classes and use annotations to intercept methods. For example there are a lot of methods where I need to check if the user is the owner of the entity he wants to alter (in my case this is a project). Therefor within the interceptor I need to make database calls and though having the appropriate DAOs injected would be the best way to go.

Currently my interceptor looks like this:

```java
 public class ProjectOwnerCheckInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

        @Inject
        private EntityManager em;

        @Inject
        private UserProvider userProvider;

        @Inject
        private RMUserDAO rmUserDAO;

        @Inject
        private ProjectDAO projectDAO;

        public ProjectOwnerCheckInterceptor() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public Object invoke(MethodInvocation arg0) throws Throwable {

            // First of all let's get the annotation
            ProjectOwnerCheck check = arg0.getMethod().getAnnotation(ProjectOwnerCheck.class);

            // if there is no check, then just proceed!
            if (check == null)
                arg0.proceed();

            long projectId = (long) arg0.getArguments()         [check.projectIdIndex()];

            // Handling ownership!!
            Project project = getProjectOrThrow(projectId);

            return arg0.proceed();

        }
    }
```

The custom annotation is straight forward. I need to add some little information which argument position the entityId in the method has to check is as number of parameters and types vary:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
public @interface ProjectOwnerCheck {

    int projectIdIndex() default -1;

}
```

For Jersey/HK2 to know what to do with the interceptors I have created a filter implementing InterceptionService:

```java
public class HK2InterceptorFilter implements InterceptionService {

    private final static MethodInterceptor PROJECT_CHECK_METHOD_INTERCEPTOR = new ProjectOwnerCheckInterceptor();
    private final static List<MethodInterceptor> PROJECT_CHECK_METHOD_LIST = Collections
            .singletonList(PROJECT_CHECK_METHOD_INTERCEPTOR);

    public HK2InterceptorFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getDescriptorFilter() {

        return BuilderHelper.allFilter();

    }

    @Override
    public List<MethodInterceptor> getMethodInterceptors(Method method) {

        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(ProjectOwnerCheck.class))
            return PROJECT_CHECK_METHOD_LIST;

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public List<ConstructorInterceptor> getConstructorInterceptors(Constructor<?> constructor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

I am binding that Filter in my JerseyApplication class:

```java
register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                try {

                    bind(HK2InterceptorFilter.class).to(InterceptionService.class).in(Singleton.class);
                    bind(getPasswordStorage()).to(PasswordStorage.class);
                    bind(getDocumentService()).to(DocumentService.class);
                    bind(UserManagementAccessor.getUserProvider()).to(UserProvider.class);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new InternalServerErrorException(e);
                }
            }
        });
```

When set a breakpoint in my interceptor I can see that it is correctly instantiated and the method gots called. But what I totally miss are all those @Inject fields I need to have to make my check. Am I missing something or is this in HK2 not possible. I used to work with Guice and there it is working (I am - due to the fact the app's code base is quite large, but time limited - bound to HK2:) ).

Thanks for all your help in advance!

PS:

I am using Jersey 2.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the interceptor never goes through the DI lifecycle because if is not a service in the container. You are instantiating it yourself. When you do this in a DI framework, the majority of the time you can expect this result.

What you *can* do though is explicitly inject it yourself using HK2 container, the `ServiceLocator`. You inject the locator into the `InterceptionService`, and then call `locator.inject(interceptor)`. This method is a general purpose method to explicitly inject *any* arbitrary object. So you might change it something like

```
private final List<MethodInterceptor> PROJECT_CHECK_METHOD_LIST;

@Inject
public HK2InterceptorFilter(ServiceLocator locator) {
    final MethodIntercator i = new ProjectOwnerCheckInterceptor();
    locator.inject(i)
    PROJECT_CHECK_METHOD_LIST = Collections.singletonList(i);
}
```

The other problem you are going to face is that the interceptor is a singleton, but all your service you are trying to inject into look like they are request scoped. This is a problem, as they need to change on a per request basis. For this what we can do is make them proxies. We can do this simply by chaining a couple method in the binding

```
bind(getPasswordStorage())
    .to(PasswordStorage.class)
    .proxy(true)
    .proxyForSameScope(false)
    .in(RequestScoped.class);
```

**See Also:** [Injecting Request Scoped Objects into Singleton Scoped Object with HK2 and Jersey](http://paulsamsotha.blogspot.com/2015/12/injecting-request-scoped-objects-into.html)

Below is a complete example using [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html).

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.aopalliance.intercept.ConstructorInterceptor;
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor;
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.Filter;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.InterceptionService;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.BuilderHelper;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.containsString;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

/**
 * Stack Overflow question http://stackoverflow.com/q/36859669/2587435
 * 
 * Run this like any other JUnit test. One one required test dependency:
 * 
 * <dependency>
 *     <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
 *     <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory</artifactId>
 *     <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
 * </dependency>
 *
 * @author Paul Samsotha
 */
public class InterceptionTest extends JerseyTest {

    public static interface HeaderProvider {
        String getXCustomHeader();
    }

    public static class HeaderProviderImpl implements HeaderProvider {
        @Context
        private HttpHeaders headers;

        @Override
        public String getXCustomHeader() {
            return headers.getHeaderString("X-Custom-Header");
        }
    }

    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public static @interface Intercept {
    }

    public static class MyMethodInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

        @Inject
        private HeaderProvider provider;

        @Override
        public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
            return provider.getClass().getName() + ":" + provider.getXCustomHeader();
        }

    }

    public static class InterceptionHandler implements InterceptionService {

        private final List<MethodInterceptor> interceptors;

        @Inject
        public InterceptionHandler(ServiceLocator locator) {
            final MethodInterceptor interceptor = new MyMethodInterceptor();
            locator.inject(interceptor);
            interceptors = Collections.singletonList(interceptor);
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getDescriptorFilter() {
            return BuilderHelper.allFilter();
        }

        @Override
        public List<MethodInterceptor> getMethodInterceptors(Method method) {
            if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Intercept.class)) {
                return interceptors;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public List<ConstructorInterceptor> getConstructorInterceptors(Constructor<?> c) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static class Binder extends AbstractBinder {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(InterceptionHandler.class)
                    .to(InterceptionService.class)
                    .in(Singleton.class);
            bind(HeaderProviderImpl.class)
                    .to(HeaderProvider.class)
                    .proxy(true)
                    .proxyForSameScope(false)
                    .in(RequestScoped.class);
        }
    }

    @Path("intercept")
    public static class TestResource {

        @GET
        @Intercept
        public String get() {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(TestResource.class)
                .register(new Binder())
                .register(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getAnonymousLogger(), true));          
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnHeaderAndProxyClass() {
        Response response = target("intercept").request()
                .header("X-Custom-Header", "Value1")
                .get();
        assertThat(response.getStatus(), is(200));
        String entity = response.readEntity(String.class);
        response.close();
        assertThat(entity, containsString("Value1"));
        assertThat(entity, containsString("Proxy"));

        // Change header to make sure we aren't getting the same HttpHeaders instance
        response = target("intercept").request()
                .header("X-Custom-Header", "Value2")
                .get();
        assertThat(response.getStatus(), is(200));
        entity = response.readEntity(String.class);
        response.close();
        assertThat(entity, containsString("Value2"));
        assertThat(entity, containsString("Proxy"));
    }
}
```